# Cannot access webapi Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using .net framework 4.5.2 and asp.net web api.

I create a new controller called LoginVerification and when I run the application I don't see the controller under the api tab.  Also, when I try to do a get or post in Postman by going to http://localhost:51449/api/LoginVerification I get the following error:

```
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51449/api/LoginVerification'.",
"MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'LoginVerification'."
```

I'm not sure why I can't navigate to the LoginVerification Controller.

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/LoginVerification")]
public class LoginVerificationController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
        retVal = loginModel.VerifyLoginValue(value);

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(retVal, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: You are missing route attributes on the ApiController actions. By using `RoutePrefix` you tell the route table that this controller is using attribute routing so the actions would need attributes as well

Comment: Even without the RoutePrefix it isn’t working

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Route` attributes on the `ApiController` actions. By using `RoutePrefix` you tell the route table that this controller is using attribute routing so the actions would need attributes as well

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/LoginVerification")]
public class LoginVerificationController : ApiController {
    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id) {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value) {
        //...
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id:int}"]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id:int}"]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Finally ensure that attribute routing is enabled in `WebApiConfig`

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I suggest `[Route("api/[controller]")]` if you are using asp.net core.  I realize the question is not specifically about this but others may find this suggestions useful.